# Can I modify a map that is managed with a gen_server with external functions?

Tags: erlang, gen-server

I have a map that is managed with a module with a gen_server behavior, where I'm able to add, remove and update key->values.

I also have a main module with some routines and subroutines where I act depending on the key->values that I have in the map. My problem is that I try to modify the map during the execution of my module, but I didn't get any answer.

This is an example of the structure of my main module:

```
-export([
    go/0, 
    add_belief/1
]).

go()->
    bs:start_link(),
    collect_bottles(0).

collect_bottles(Total) ->
    case {bs:is_belief(holding), bs:is_belief(over_drop)} of
        {true, true} -> drop_and_leave();
        {true,false} -> get_to_drop();
        {false, _} -> get_bottle()
    end.

get_bottle()->
io:format("Getting bottle.~n"),
case {bs:get_belief(see)} of
    {true} -> collect_bottles(bs:get_belief(collected)); 
    {false} ->move(),
              get_bottle()
end.

move(Dist)->
io:format("Start moving...~n"),
timer:sleep(5000).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%            GOD FUNCTIONS             %%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

add_belief(Belief)->
    bs:add_belief(Belief).
```

The code of `bs:add_belief(Belief)` is:

```
add_belief(Belief)->
    gen_server:cast(?MODULE,{add,Belief}).
```

And in the `gen_server` function:

```
handle_cast({add,{Key,Value}},State)->
    io:format("Belief added: ~p.~n",[{Key,Value}]),
    {noreply, maps:put(Key,Value,State)};
```

When I run my script, I get:

```
tr:go().
Getting bottle.
Start moving...
Getting bottle.
Start moving...
```

And I can't not use another function (I would like to use `add_belief({see,bottle})` to get out of the loop.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and what exactly is not working?

Comment: I execute go(), so it starts to work. Then, while it is executing, I do some add_belief(Belief) from the shell, to change the map and access to other statement of the case. For example: my map is {holding=>[], over_drop=>[]}, so in collect_bottles I can access to {true,true}->drop_and_leave. Now I want to add_belief({gripper_open,[]}) to be able to access to the true statement in drop_and_leave(), but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You should post the code for `bs:add_belief(Belief)`

Comment: Lets see If I follow you. You can do ´add_belief´, you do that at the beginning and you can test results. You should also see a few "Belief added..." printed on the shell. Now you do ´add_belief({gripper_open,[]})´ and nothing happens. It doesn't even get to write "Belief added..." into the shell. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, in the pattern matching bs:is_belief(Belief) works perfectly, but I can't modify my map once my code is running (I don't see any Belief added.. when I call the add_belief function in the shell)

Comment: Oh wait if you don't see "Belief added" you're not matching. post your shell command and other handle_cast in your bs module

Comment: My script has other functions that can add beliefs properly, but when I use this function externally, I don't receive any special message, I mean, I keep watching the prints of my go() routine, but no the one that is as result of add_belief().

Comment: I can't help you without see your code. add a print statement in the other handle_cast. and without knowing what you write in the shell, I could safly guess you're inputing the wrong tuple.

Comment: would be better if you provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have put an example of the messages that I get, all of them are prints from my routines. But I dont get any from the bs:add_belief(Belief).

Comment: I have tried to put a MCVE example of the code, I don't know if I've done it properly. For me it's difficult to do it without including the whole code.

Comment: Edited to get a better MCVE example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I modify a map that is managed with a gen_server with external
>   functions?

Yes, here is proof:

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)

1> c(tr).
{ok,tr}

2> c(bs).
{ok,bs}

3> c(env).
{ok,env}

4> tr:test().
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
<0.74.0>
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle

5> env:get_state().
env: get_state(): 10
ok
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle

6> bs:get_state().
bs:get_state(): #{}
ok
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle 

7> bs:add_belief({holding, []}).
Adding belief: {holding,[]}
ok
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle

8> bs:get_state().
bs:get_state(): #{holding=>[]}
ok
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle

9> 
BREAK: (a)bort (c)ontinue (p)roc info (i)nfo (l)oaded
       (v)ersion (k)ill (D)b-tables (d)istribution
$
```

If instead I change my `bs:erl` file to call `gen_server:start_link()` like this:

```
start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link(
      %%{local, ?MODULE},
      ?MODULE, [], []
    ).
```

then this is what happens:

```
1> c(tr).
{ok,tr}

2> c(bs).
{ok,bs}

3> c(env).
{ok,env}

4> tr:test().
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
<0.74.0>
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle 

5> bs:add_belief({holding, []}).
ok
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle

6> bs:get_state().
** exception exit: {noproc,{gen_server,call,[bs,get_state]}}
     in function  gen_server:call/2 (gen_server.erl, line 204)
     in call from bs:get_state/0 (bs.erl, line 40)
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle
```

From the [gen_server docs](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/gen_server_concepts.html#id64544) about `gen_server:start_link()`:

> The first argument, {local, ch3}, specifies the name. The gen_server
>   is then locally registered as ch3.
>
> If the name is omitted, the gen_server is not registered. Instead its
>   pid must be used. The name can also be given as {global, Name}, in
>   which case the gen_server is registered using global:register_name/2.

If you don't specify `{local, ?MODULE}` as an argument to `gen_server:start_link()`, then you have to call `gen_server:call()` like this:

```
 gen_server:call(ServerPid, Request)
```

To get the ServerPid, you need to do something like this:

```
start_link() ->
    {ok, ServerPid} = gen_server:start_link(
                          %%{local, ?MODULE},
                          ?MODULE, [], []
                      ),
    ServerPid.
```

From the last shell session above, it looks like if you don't specify `{local, ServerName}`--and thus you do not register the server name--and you call `gen_server:cast(?MODULE, ...)` it won't cause an error, but if you call `gen_server:call(?MODULE...)` you will get an error.  To me it seems like it would be handy if you got an error in both cases when the server wasn't registered--the return value of `ok` for the cast is pretty misleading.

---

`tr.erl`:

```
-module(tr).
%%-compile(export_all).
-export([go/0, test/0]).

go() ->
    bs:start_link(),
    env:start_link(),
    collect_bottles(0).

collect_bottles(_Total) ->
    get_bottle().

get_bottle() ->
    io:format("tr:get_bottle(): getting bottle~n"),
    timer:sleep(3000),
    get_bottle().

test() ->
    spawn(tr, go, []).
```

`bs.erl`:

```
-module(bs).
%%-compile(export_all).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2]).
-export([handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).
-export([start_link/0, add_belief/1, get_state/0, stop/0]).


%%Internal server functions:
init([]) ->
    {ok, #{}}.  %%<******** INITIALIZE STATE WITH AN EMPTY MAP

handle_cast({add, {Key, Val}=Belief}, State) ->
    io:format("Adding belief: ~w~n", [Belief]),
    { noreply, maps:put(Key, Val, State) }.

handle_call(get_state, _From, State) ->
    {reply, State, State}.    

%  -----
handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

%%External interface:
start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link(
      {local, ?MODULE},
      ?MODULE, [], []
    ).

add_belief(Belief) ->  %%<******* EXTERNAL FUNCTION THAT MODIFIES A MAP
    gen_server:cast(?MODULE, {add, Belief}).

get_state() ->
    State = gen_server:call(?MODULE, get_state),
    io:format("bs:get_state(): ~w~n", [State]).

stop() ->
    gen_server:stop(?MODULE).
```

`env.erl`:

```
-module(env).
%%-compile(export_all).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2]).
-export([handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).
-export([start_link/0, get_state/0, stop/0]).

%%Internal server functions:
init([]) ->
    {ok, 10}.   %%<***** INITIALIZE STATE WITH 10

handle_call(get_state, _From, State) ->
    {reply, State, State}.

%%     ------
handle_cast(_Request, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.    

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

%%External interface:
start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link(
      {local, ?MODULE},
      ?MODULE, [], []
    ).

get_state() ->
    State = gen_server:call(?MODULE, get_state),
    io:format("env: get_state(): ~w~n", [State]).

stop() ->
    gen_server:stop(?MODULE).
```

Comment: My start_link() function was the same that you indicated me. I have edited my post again (trying to do a better MCVE), because I didn't realize that I was using Erlide and this was the reason why I could write in the console but I didn't get any answer. If I run from werl, I can't introduce a new command while my script is running.

Comment: @Antolinos95, *I can't introduce a new command while my script is running.* -- I think you have a couple of options: 1) spawn the go() function.  See how I did that in my test() function?  2) put all the erlang shell commands that you want to run inside go() and intersperse some `timer:sleep()`'s.

Comment: @Antolinos95, In fact, I didn't even type in the erlang shell to compile your three modules when I was testing your code--it's way too much of a pain. Instead, I created a bash shell script named `run` to do the compiling for me, which contains these lines: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and `erlc -W tr.erl env.erl bs.erl` and `erl -s tr test`. That way I just had to type `$ ./run` on the command line the first time I ran your program, then I killed the erlang shell with Ctrl+CC, and to recompile and run agaiin, I just hit the up arrow key to get to the previous command:`./run`, and hit Return.

Comment: @Antolinos95, If you want to save yourself a lot of time and frustration, learn how to do the equivalent on windows.  You could use a batch file, perl, ruby, python or a makefile to run those erlang commands.  At the very least, you should be able to compile from the command line like this:  `$ erlc -W tr.erl bs.erl env.erl` then `$ erl -s tr go`  and put all your erlang shell commands inside go().  Then you can kill the erlang shell with `Ctrl+CC` and recompile and run by hitting the up arrow to get to the previous commands and hitting Return, which will save you a lot of typing.

Comment: I'm going to try the two options. Regarding to the erlang compilation, I'm using an extension of Eclipse to work with it, because for me (I'm a beginner) it's easier, since I've use Eclipse with Java.

Comment: With the first option it works perfectly! Thank you so much :D